# L_0 regularizaion in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I would Like to use L_0 regularization for a NN in TensorFlow, meaning, regularization on the number of features among all input features which will be considered.  What's the best way doing so?
thanks

Comment: Do you mean the sum of tensor dimensions (except batch size)?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't accurate: usually, L_0 (or other L_i) regularization refers to the last layer. I would like to apply regularization on the weights connecting the input layer to the first hidden layer; regularization which favors applying 0 over other wights.

Comment: I'm just confused by L_0: L_1 is the sum of abs weights, L_2 is the sum of squares and so on. What is L_0?

Comment: L_0 is the sum of the binarization of the weights - each weight contributes 1 if the weight is greater than 0, 0 otherwise.